# Laravel - Create user profile with user id

Tags: laravel-4

In my app I have a users table and a user_profiles table.
When creating a new user I need to fill the new users ID in the user_profile table.

Here is my store function in my users controller

```
public function store()
{
    $userData = new User(Input::only('username'));
    $userProfileData = new UserProfile(Input::except('username'));


    $userData->save();
    $userProfileData->save();

    Flash::success('A new user has been created successfully.');
    return Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

How can I pass the newly created users id to the users_id column in the users_profile table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting and assigning the ID might be easier than you think:

```
    public function store()
{
    $userData = new User(Input::only('username'));
    $userProfileData = new UserProfile(Input::except('username'));


    $userData->save();
    $userProfileData->users_id = $userData->id;
    $userProfileData->save();

    Flash::success('A new user has been created successfully.');
    return Redirect::route('users.index');
}
```

The id will be set in the $userData object after the execution of the save() method on the userData object. You can then assign it to the foreign key in user_profiles object.

Comment: You are right. I was way over thinking it. Thanks for that!